# How to get month and day in android?

Tags: java, android, datetime

I need to get month and day as :01 for January, 02 for February... and 01 for first day of month, etc... I tried this :

```
 String dd = c.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-" 
        + c.get(Calendar.MONTH)
        + "-" + c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) 
        + " " + c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) 
        + ":" + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)
        + ":" + c.get((Calendar.SECOND));
```

but I get something like this :

```
2011-8-1 12:05:20
```

Which is the solution of this problem? For month I think I have to add 1,right?

Comment: You want to get current day and month?

Comment: you're right month in java Calendar are zero based (0 to 11) adding 1 fix the value to be human readable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're over-complicating the problem.  If all you need is to format a date in a certain way, then use `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` class.  See the documentation here: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

If you really do need to get individual parts, then you are correct in using `Calendar.get` method.  I suggest you read up on `java.util.Calendar`.

Answer (score 13):

```
        String month=c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1+"";
    if(month.length()<2){
         month="0"+month;   
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

```
Date date = calendar.getTime();
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
String formattedDate = format.format(date);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Log.e("TEST",sdf.format(new Date()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this to get date and time:

```
    Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();
    String y = String.valueOf(rightNow.getTime().getYear());
    String ym = String.valueOf(rightNow.getTime().getMonth());
    String yd = String.valueOf(rightNow.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    String h = String.valueOf(rightNow.getTime().getHours());
    String hm = String.valueOf(rightNow.getTime().getMinutes());
    String hs = String.valueOf(rightNow.getTime().getSeconds());
```

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime.now( ZonedId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ).format( DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME ).replace( "T" , " " )
```

## Details

> Which is the solution of this problem? For month I think I have to add 1,right?

Nope, not if you use better classes. You are using troublesome, confusing, poorly designed date-time classes which should be avoided. Instead use java.time classes.

## `ZonedDateTime`

Get the current moment in your desired/expected time zone. Get a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZonedId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( zoneId );
```

Interrogate for the parts if that is what you need. The java.time classes count month sensibly, 1-12 is January-December. By the way, check out the handy [`Month`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum.

```
int month = zdt.getMonthValue();
int dayOfMonth = zdt.getDayOfMonth();
```

To get literally the string you showed, let the [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class do the work. The predefined formatter [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME) gets you nearly there. You can replace the `T` in the middle with a SPACE to finish.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME ;
String output = zdt.format( f ).replace( "T" , " " );
```

## java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the old troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time.