# How to get current date and time in Android?

Tags: android

There are many questions like this on StackOverflow but no one has the answer I need. I have seen these 3 questions:

[Get Value Of Day Month form Date Object in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17192776/get-value-of-day-month-form-date-object-in-android)
[How to get month and day in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268192/how-to-get-month-and-day-in-android)
[Get current time and date on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369682/get-current-time-and-date-on-android)

From these 3 questions I have learnt that to get date and time, we need to use Calendar. I have visited its documentation page but that is too hard to understand.

Now my question is I want to get current day i.e 12, current month i.e November, current year i.e 2014 and hour, minute, not seconds and AM or PM.

I only know till here:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
```

Now what should I do next?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change date from 24-hours format to 12-hours format (am/pm) in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9532463/how-can-i-change-date-from-24-hours-format-to-12-hours-format-am-pm-in-android)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
    Calendar calander = Calendar.getInstance(); 
    cDay = calander.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    cMonth = calander.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    cYear = calander.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    selectedMonth = "" + cMonth;
    selectedYear = "" + cYear;
    cHour = calander.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    cMinute = calander.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    cSecond = calander.get(Calendar.SECOND);
```

Comment: FYI, the troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Most *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android (<26) in [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 14):

You can customize the format you want using

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy, HH:mm");
String date = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to get date and time in desired format :

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd,MMMM,YYYY hh,mm,a");
String strDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    Calendar localCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
    Date currentTime = localCalendar.getTime();
    int currentDay = localCalendar.get(Calendar.DATE);
    int currentMonth = localCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    int currentYear = localCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int currentDayOfWeek = localCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    int currentDayOfMonth = localCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int CurrentDayOfYear = localCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);

    System.out.println("Current Date and time details in local timezone");
    System.out.println("Current Date: " + currentTime);
    System.out.println("Current Day: " + currentDay);
    System.out.println("Current Month: " + currentMonth);
    System.out.println("Current Year: " + currentYear);
    System.out.println("Current Day of Week: " + currentDayOfWeek);
    System.out.println("Current Day of Month: " + currentDayOfMonth);
    System.out.println("Current Day of Year: " + CurrentDayOfYear);
```

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

> I want to get current day i.e 12, current month i.e November, current year i.e 2014 and hour, minute, not seconds and AM or PM.

```
ZonedDateTime
.now( 
    ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" )    // Or "Asia/India", "Africa/Tunis", etc.
)
.format(
    DateTimeFormatter
    .ofPattern(
        "dd MMMM uuuu HH:mm" 
    )
    .withLocale( 
        Locale.CANADA_FRENCH           // Or `Locale.US`, or `new Locale( "en" , "IN" )` for English language with India culture.
    )
)
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/DyM0vQ).

> 28 septembre 2019 08:48

## *java.time*

> From these 3 questions I have learnt that to get date and time, we need to use Calendar.

Nope.

The `Calendar` class is terrible, along with `Date` & `SimpleDateFormat` and such. These classes were all supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

> Now my question is I want to get current day i.e 12, current month i.e November, current year i.e 2014 and hour, minute, not seconds and AM or PM.

Determining a date and time-of-day requires a time zone. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may [change at any moment](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TimeZone.html#setDefault(java.util.TimeZone)) during runtime(!), so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument. If you want to depend on the JVM’s current default time zone, make your intention clear by calling `ZoneId.systemDefault()`. If critical, confirm the zone with your user.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ;
```

Capture the current moment as seen in the wall-clock time used by the people of a certain region (a time zone).

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

If you do not care about the seconds or fractional-second, truncate.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ).truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.MINUTES ) ;
```

Generate a string in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, wisely extended to append the name of the time zone in square brackets.

```
String output = zdt.toString() ;
```

> 2019-09-28T01:42+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]

Generate a string, automatically localized.

```
Locale locale = new Locale( "en" , "IN" ) ;  // English language, India culture.
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.LONG ).withLocale( locale ) ;
String output2 = zdt.format( f ) ;
```

> 28 September 2019 at 1:42:00 AM IST

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/DyM0vQ).

---

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]

Comment: you can use java.time in older API with Java 8+ API desugaring support (https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class XYZ extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println("Current time => "+c.getTime());

    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
    // formattedDate have current date/time
    Toast.makeText(this, formattedDate, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


  // Now we display formattedDate value in TextView
    TextView txtView = new TextView(this);
    txtView.setText("Current Date and Time : "+formattedDate);
    txtView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    txtView.setTextSize(20);
    setContentView(txtView);
  }

 }


Calendar calander = Calendar.getInstance(); 
cDay = calander.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
cMonth = calander.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
cYear = calander.get(Calendar.YEAR);
selectedMonth = "" + cMonth;
selectedYear = "" + cYear;
cHour = calander.get(Calendar.HOUR);
cMinute = calander.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
cSecond = calander.get(Calendar.SECOND);
```

Comment: I want date and time in parts. Current day in int, name of month in String, year in int, hour and minute in int and AM or PM in String.

Comment: Change the arguments supplied to the SimpleDateFormat in my answer above and to get integers use Integer.parseInt(string) to convert those that you need as integers